# MCU to MCU Communication with Profibus/Profinet?

Tags: arm, embedded, communication, stm32

Is that a possible communication between two STM32f4 devices with Profibus/Profinet  Protocole. I can not find any information this question. I want to MASTER to SLAVE communication. And i want to send message/data between.

Comment: Of course it is possible, although cumbersome. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You can buy a reliable PROFINET stack for less than ~200K or build your own. Profibus is much simpler(but still not simple), but without more details I would suggest to use an even more simpler protocol

Comment: @jeb 200k what? I really hope that's some exotic currency and not dollar or euro. Protocol stacks tend to cost roughly around 10k€, in my experience.

Comment: @Lundin No, it's Euro and in my case I suppose the price for my current company is even higher

Comment: @jeb Wow, that's... awful. You could buy hundreds of Profinet gateways for the same kind of cash, not counting the development cost of adapting the stack to your application.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, but we are developing the PLC's and everything else. And a full featured Profinet stack isn't just a simple piece of software, it's really complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profibus is not really designed for MCU to MCU communications. The only reason you would use it is if they are some distance apart and you had one master and multiple slaves. Profibus DP generally requires a specific Profibus IC (such as Profichip) to implement a Slave module as the timing is critical. Similarly implementing a Master is also a complex affair. It is meant to be used as a field bus (for use over entire factories or sites etc.)

I don't know that much about Profinet, but I doubt it is what you want for MCU to MCU comms.

If the processors are in the same device I2C would probably be your best bet and is physically supported by the STM32F4 (you would need a protocol on top this as well).

Comment: It should be noted that Profibus is old technology. CAN is a much better choice for new system design. Or maybe Ethernet for high data loads/non-critical communication.

Comment: Profibus and CAN are meant for entirely different purposes.

Comment: Not really, CAN is merely a newer technology that can do the same, in safer and less complicated ways. It lacks higher baudrates though (except for the new CAN FD). Profibus is legacy technology that would have died some 30 years ago, if not for Siemens.

Comment: CAN is meant for short(ish) range communications whereas Profibus can be wired round an entire site and controlled from a PLC. Profibus is still very much in use for industrial automation and is still being installed in many places.

Comment: You can have 1km CAN bus at < 50kbps, following by for example the recommendations in CANopen DS303-1 5.1. Though more realistic use-cases are up to 500m/125kbps or 100m/500kbps. Though the main reason to avoid Profibus is the complexity, star net topology etc. As well as all the old legacy UART stuff. The trend I see in automation is that Profibus/Profinet is getting phased out in favour of CAN or Ethernet. It's mostly just the Siemens PLC branch being conservative, hugging their 1980s technologies.

Comment: I want to talk to two PC with profinet/profibus using python actuallly how can i do this ?